# data type mismatch with mathematical operators on integer generated by custom function

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to run a really simple select query on MS Access which calls a custom function made by somebody else.  The function returns an integer, yet when I try and apply criteria with simple operators, I'm told there's a data type mismatch.  It's frustrating as just before I get this message and the values are all replaced with '#NAME?', I see the correct information has been returned.  Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong?

The query is:

```
SELECT p.nhs_number, age(p.date_of_birth) AS age
FROM patient_tbl AS p
WHERE (((age(p.date_of_birth))<16));
```

The function is:

```
' Returns the difference in full years from DateOfBirth to current date,
' optionally to another date.
' Returns zero if AnotherDate is earlier than DateOfBirth.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   any date/time value of data type Date
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28th when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29th
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2015-11-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Age( _
ByVal DateOfBirth As Date, _
Optional ByVal AnotherDate As Variant) _
As Integer

Dim ThisDate    As Date
Dim Years       As Integer
 
If IsDate(AnotherDate) Then
    ThisDate = CDate(AnotherDate)
Else
    ThisDate = Date
End If

' Find difference in calendar years.
Years = DateDiff("yyyy", DateOfBirth, ThisDate)
If Years > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of DateOfBirth.
    If DateDiff("d", ThisDate, DateAdd("yyyy", Years, DateOfBirth)) > 0 Then
        Years = Years - 1
    End If
ElseIf Years < 0 Then
    Years = 0
End If

Age = Years
 
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `p.date_of_birth` is not a `date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some *Null* values.

Try to exclude these:

```sql
SELECT p.nhs_number, age(p.date_of_birth) AS age
FROM patient_tbl AS p
WHERE (p.date_of_birth Is Not Null) And (age(p.date_of_birth)<16);
```

or substitute them:

```sql
SELECT p.nhs_number, age(Nz(p.date_of_birth, Date())) AS age
FROM patient_tbl AS p
WHERE age(Nz(p.date_of_birth, Date()))<16;
```